# Loading Icons from CSS files based on props passed in a component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, kendo-ui

I want to store icons in CSS files and load them from there based on the props passed in a component.

Is this possible?

In the following example
[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/w2gw6q?file=/app/main.tsx)

If one goes into this above link there the SVG icons have been loaded from the library `'@progress/kendo-svg-icons'`.
Can one store these icons from the SVG library into a CSS file and based on the custom props passed inside any component load it from the CSS rather than loading the library in the script file?

Like in the below example

```
  import from './ButtonStyles.css'
  .....
  <React.Fagment>
  .....
   <button icon="eyeIcon">Hello</button>
  ....
  </React.Fragment>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Any sample code will be also highly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution

```
// Define the CSS classes for the icons in a CSS file (e.g., ButtonStyles.css):

.eyeIcon {
  background-image: url('path/to/eye-icon.svg');
}

.penIcon {
  background-image: url('path/to/pen-icon.svg');
}

// Import the CSS file in the component:

import './ButtonStyles.css';

// Define a function that maps the icon prop value to the corresponding CSS class:
actionscript

function getIconClass(icon) {
  switch (icon) {
    case 'eyeIcon':
      return 'eyeIcon';
    case 'penIcon':
      return 'penIcon';
    default:
      return '';
  }
}

// Use the getIconClass function to set the CSS class of the button element based on the icon prop:

function Button({ icon, children }) {
  const iconClass = getIconClass(icon);

  return (
    <button className={iconClass}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}
// Use the Button component with the icon prop:

<Button icon="eyeIcon">Hello</Button>
```

Hope this will help you